# Launchpad build error - missing libgtk3

Tags: packaging, launchpad

I've just tried to upload my first ubuntu package to ppa and I got:

```
dh_strip debug symbol extraction: disabling for PPA build
dh_strip debug symbol extraction: not doing anything since NO_PKG_MANGLE is given
   dh_makeshlibs
   dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgtk-3.so.0 needed by debian/mypackage/opt/mypackage/mypackage (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '').
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgdk-3.so.0 needed by debian/mypackage/opt/mypackage/mypackage (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '').
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: Cannot continue due to the errors listed above.
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/mypackage.substvars debian/mypackage/opt/mypackage/mypackage returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 2
```

dpkg-buildpackage: error: /usr/bin/fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2

I added dependency: libgtk-3-0 (>=3.0.0), but it didn't help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add libgtk-3-0 as build dependency (Build-Depends) in debian/control file.

Comment: I tried to add libgtk-3-0 (>=3.0.0) but it didn't help.

Comment: My bad. I added dependency, but not build dependency! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Same error before add the build dependency?